# perl reference confusion using hash value being array

Tags: perl

While looking at 
http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/references.html

From below, I really don't understand
 `@{ $table{$state} }`

It explains that this is hash table whose key is `$state` and value is array..   so this is basically
taking normal `%table` and whose values will be array.. is this the right way to look at this?

Is there also such thing as `%{ $table{$state} }`   ? I don't even know if this means anything.

```
 1  while (<>) {
 2    chomp;
 3    my ($city, $state) = split /, /;
 4    push @{$table{$state}}, $city;
 5  }
 6
 7  foreach $state (sort keys %table) {
 8    print "$state: ";
 9    my @cities = @{$table{$state}};
10        print join ', ', sort @cities;
11    print ".\n";
12  }
```

Comment: Please check [`HoA`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS) and [`HoH`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@{  }` is a dereference. It's saying that the *expected* value in `$table{$state}` is an array reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %table = (
   firstkey   => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
   secondkey => [ 'fish', 'bird', 'bat' ],
);


foreach my $key ( keys %table ) {
   print $key, " is ", ref ( $table{$key} ), " with a value of ", $table{$key}, "\n";

   foreach my $value ( @{$table{$key}} ) {
       print "\t$value\n";
   }
}
```

`%{ $table{$state} }` would work *if* there was a hash reference in there instead of an array reference.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %table = (
   firstkey => { fish => 1, bird => 2, bat => 3 }
);


foreach my $key ( keys %table ) {
   print $key, " is ", ref ( $table{$key} ), " with a value of ", $table{$key}, "\n";

   foreach my $subkey ( keys %{$table{$key}} ) {
       print "$subkey => $table{$key}{$subkey}\n"
   }
}
```

The core of this is down to how perl implements multi dimensional data structures - it does so via storing references in the single 'value' of the sub-array.